# How To iterate through an array which are nodal values in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I have an ArrayList which have arrays as its value. Now I want to iterate through each ArrayList node and also through all the respective array index at each node. What should be the best way to do so if I want to display a whole nodal index (all the array components in that node) in a single line.

consider an:

```
ArrayList<String[]> arr_list =  new ArrayList<String[]>;
String array1[] = {"4","5","3","2"};
String array2[] = {"7","1","0","9"};
String array3[] = {"8","4","3","1"};
arr_list.add(0,array1);
arr_list.add(1,array2);
arr_list.add(2,array3);
```

I need to display it in this format(here starting number in each line is nodal-index)

```
0 : 4 5 3 2
1 : 7 1 0 9
2 : 8 4 3 1
```

Comment: how do you expect to put in a list of Strings[] a bunch of int[] ?????

Comment: my mistake.  Corrected

Answer (score 1):

Use a double loop, the first one to iterate through the ArrayList, and the second one to iterate through each arrays. On a side note, your arrays should be String arrays, or nothing will ever work.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr_list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " : ");
    for (int j = 0; j < arr_list.get(i).length; j++) {
        System.out.print(arr_list.get(i)[j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: Can we use a iterator ?

Comment: Sure, but I chose to use a double loop in order to print the index of each of your arrays easily. An iterator would surely do the trick too though

Answer (score 1):

define a list of list that you can loop on :

```
List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(Arrays.asList("4", "5", "3", "2"));
l.add(Arrays.asList("7", "1", "0", "9"));
l.add(Arrays.asList("8", "4", "3", "1"));

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " : " + l.get(i));
}
```

---

just in case you dont want the **[ ]** and need those space separated

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " : " + String.join(" ", l.get(i)));
}
```

---

**Edit**:

because soon or later people will need the same using java8 stream power :

```
List<List<String>> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(Arrays.asList("4", "5", "3", "2"));
l.add(Arrays.asList("7", "1", "0", "9"));
l.add(Arrays.asList("8", "4", "3", "1"));

IntStream.range(0, l.size()).forEach(x -> System.out.println(x + " : " + String.join(" ", l.get(x))));
```

Comment: This will not print the array as a space separated list.

Comment: Is there a reason why you *append* to `j` and not simply assign?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a *foreach* loop to iterate over the elements in an `ArrayList` and then we can write:

```
int idx = 0;
for(String[] row : arr_list) {
    System.out.print(idx);
    System.out.print(" :");
    for(String e : row) {
        System.out.print(' ');
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    System.out.println();
    idx++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList<int[]> arr_list =  new ArrayList<int[]>();
    int array1[] = {4,5,3,2};
    int array2[] = {7,1,0,9};
    int array3[] = {8,4,3,1};
    arr_list.add(array1);
    arr_list.add(array2);
    arr_list.add(array3);

    for(int i = 0; i<arr_list.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(i+" : ");
        for(int number : arr_list.get(i)){
            System.out.print(number+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you already get your answer, additionally

```
String[] arr = {"1","2"};
        String[] arr1 = {"3","4"};
        ArrayList<String[]> ar2 = new ArrayList<>();
        ar2.add(arr);
        ar2.add(arr1);
        int i = 0;
        for(String[] a: ar2 ){
            System.out.println(i+ ": "+Arrays.toString(a).replaceAll("[, \\[ \\]]", " "));
            i++;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Iterator` with the `ArrayList` directly by calling `.iterator()`and assign it in to iterator object, and for the array of strings you can use `foreach`:

```
        Iterator iterator = arr_list.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
           String[] array = (String[]) iterator.next();
           int index = arr_list.indexOf(array);
           System.out.print(index + " : ");
           for(String str : array){
               System.out.print(str);
           }
           System.out.println("");
        }
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a Map? Seems very doable with a

```
Map<Integer, ArrayList<String>>
```

like structure. A simple conversion of the values to integers and a traditional traversal will get what you want.